# Contacts missing after syncing with I cloud and gmail

Tags: contacts

I already synced my contacts on my iPhone 4s to my Gmail but I noticed that 
not all contacts were transferred.  I am missing 170 contacts so far still sitting on my IPhone. 
 Any explanations? How to make Gmail pick up all contacts?

Comment: can you please tell us how you did this? (transfer from iOS to Gmail? would help us a lot ... below a general answer.

Comment: Was there a Merge function, that accidentally merged contacts?

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty iOS Contact Backup Apps in the Store

- [Easy Backup](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easy-backup-my-contacts-backup/id545198169?mt=8) (free)
- [My Contacts Backup](https://itunes.apple.com/at/app/my-contacts-backup/id446784593?mt=8) (free)

So there you can export **all** contacts on the iPhone to an File and import them on [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/) - should work fine :)  let us know (with the Checkmark) if it worked for you or not :)